# Chrome doesn't receive push notifications from firebase while firefox receive notifications correctly windows

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i created a new angular project and configured push notifications with firebase FCM.when i send post request to firebase with token, firefox receive push notification correctly. but when i try with the chrome browser it doesn't receive the push notification.i'm so confused.and i'm using push API.

this is the  response after send post request to firefox with postman.

```
{
    "multicast_id": 429625283437910214,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/m/gAAAAABeFqJyd5T6UlsKzD2G28Xa0NBlU5gcliH7ty2OaFZzReU9hfJ4o8jZu6XTL-kYFGejhaf9Vqjyy4u7KTHFlF48wWXm2VymwChDWAkAqgWO7iXjcfwTMG2hizw0l9W9Li_FqS1vTMn6hhqJJUocj7efQsmZaD4J7g4IaidCRs4AURMZafIVXk2XL-7Jlj7C3Dw-NDmA"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the  response after send post request to chrome with postman.

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6540803341719147411,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1578539434037577%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

why message_id completely different in the responses?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't post screenshots of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok,thanks for the advice.i updated the question.any idea why this is happening?

Comment: after all, the problem is not on my side.it was firebase.because after a couple of weeks I received all the notifications that I send that day.i wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: having same issue, works fine in foreground and background for firefox and edge but not work in chrome background.